# Draggable input components PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to use draggable component https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dnd/draggable.xhtml for inputTextArea component but it does not work for me. Do you know any workarounds for making input components draggable?

My code:

```
<p:outputPanel>
    <p:inputTextarea id="test">
    </p:inputTextarea>
</p:outputPanel>
<p:draggable for="test" containment="parent" />
```

I don't have any errors in console. But drag function does not work as it work for p:panel, for example.

Comment: _"does not work"_ is sort of not specific. What does it do? What is your code (in [mcve] flavour)? What is your version info? Also see [ask] and

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks. I added the description

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the component in a panel and assign "for" to that panel.

```
<p:outputPanel>
    <p:panel id="test">
        <p:inputTextarea />
    </p:panel>
    <p:draggable for="test" containment="parent"/>
</p:outputPanel>
```